# zend form implementation of add another

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, socialengine

I have a zend form where I have a field add another like following

[image]

I know how to add the html when someone clicks add another button but

**`my question is how I am going to validate the dynamically added element and how I am going to dynamically generate and populate the element and how will I get this element value using zend form`**

I am using zend framework 1.

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework 1.x does not have a built in feature for this.  You have to extend the Multi Select element.  Then write a JQuery plugin to add the desired behavior.

We had to do this a couple of years back in my previous job. There is no easy way to do it.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to that old code right now.